# How to include JavaScript file into JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following script tag in my JSP file:

```
<script src="/js/CCTUtil.js"></script>
```

with the following function in it:

```
function disableButton(buttonID) {
     document.getElementById(buttonID).setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    return true;
}
```

and in my jsp I call it with:

```
onchange="disableButton('datasourceForm:cancel');
```

datasourceForm:cancel is just the ID, so don't worry about that.

This works if I hardcode the JS function in my JSP, but when exporting it to a file, it doesn't work. It recognizes the valid filepath (otherwise the server throws an exception) so it can see the file just fine, but when testing it in Internet Explorer the error is "Object expected", and points to the end of the JSP file, which of course isn't telling of anything.

Help please?

Comment: Is disableButton kept in some form of closure? (Is there a function() { that doesn't end until the bottom of the file?) See if it gets called if you reduce CCTUtil.js to JUST that function, with no other code.

Comment: Servers *do not* throw exceptions when you refer to a non-existent JS file. They just don't. Your path is undoubtedly wrong. Try adding a `.` or `..` before the initial slash.

Comment: Try specifying a type attribute in your `<script>` tag with the value as `text/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

The SRC must not be correct then. Are you sure you have set the path correctly? It's not supposed to be "../js/CCTUtil.js" is it?

Comment: The path is set correctly. I tested it with an invalid path and the server throws an exception, so the path is correct.  I tried it with both the shorthand /js/CCTUtil.js and the full directory path to it, and both trigger the "Object expected" error in IE.

Comment: [link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/738048-jsp-session-javascript-variable-problem)  see the last comment on this thread

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including `script` file, directly add `javascript` function in the jsp file. 
Then try, if you are getting the same issue, might be some issue with javascript or ur id `datasourceForm:cancel`

Comment: No, the purpose of having the JS in an external file is so I can use it with other webpages (which I will be doing). Hardcoding the JS function into every webpage is wrong.

Comment: @user3097972
i understand ur point, i was asking you to validatethe same if it works for ur single page.